# Sharepoint 2013 - Custom List View Filter - Alert me is not sending emails

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, custom-list, alert

I don’t get email alerts for a specific list view filter.. Alerts for other generic list/docs/workflow are all working… Can you guide me please?

Checked all the Immediate alerts job, List--> Advanced settings --> email etc..

All the settings are correct.

What am i missing?

Comment: What’s the filter you set in this view? Which column did you use to filter? Which column did you changed to want to get the alert email? 
Create a new view and check again. Or change other column in the list and check again.

Comment: Be sure that Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application service is turned on only on web frontend servers.

Comment: @Hellofiona_MSFT The filter is just assigned to and the view is yielding results .. I am able to select the view in Alert me window , set an alert. But emails are not sent. Tried creating views using all the templates still no luck,.. I get emails when i use available Views that are default ( My tasks , Active tasks etc)

Comment: @Raf Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application  and
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service  are running on the server

Answer (score 0):

After creating a view, go in and edit it - I just added a ".1" to the name and clicked save - it then appears as an option